# copy part of one column to another column in the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to copy part of one column into another column. The delimiter is "-". I don't want to remove that part from the first column.

Example:

```
ItemDesc            Part#
Glowear_black-1234
```

So it needs to look like this:

```
ItemDesc            Part#
Glowear_black-1234  1234
```

The only SQL query I can find cuts the information from the ItemDesc column and pastes it into Part#. I still need the "1234" in the first column. Also not all of the ItemDesc have a "-" (which is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access SQL, you can use `InStr()` to find the position of *"-"* within your field.  Then you can use `Mid()` to return the substring which starts one character after that position.

Note you must bracket `Part#` in your SQL statement because of the `#` character in its name.

```sql
UPDATE tblIOT1
SET [Part#] =
    Mid(ItemDesc, InStr(1, ItemDesc, "-") + 1)
```

If `ItemDesc` could be Null or contain a string without a *"-"*, add a `WHERE` clause to ignore those rows in the `UPDATE`.

```sql
WHERE ItemDesc ALike '%-%'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Is it possible to include a statement that won't copy over the fields without "-"?

Comment: Add that `WHERE` clause so the `UPDATE` will only be applied to rows where `ItemDesc` includes a "-".

Comment: I added the Where clause... The fields that do not contain an "-" just copies the entire field over.

Comment: I don't understand how that can happen.  Is this the query you're using now? `UPDATE tblIOT1
SET [Part#] =
    Mid(ItemDesc, InStr(1, ItemDesc, "-") + 1) WHERE ItemDesc ALike '%-%'`

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example one of the ItemDesc is Ergodyne_Test (note it's an underscore and not a hypen) and it's returning Ergodyne_Test in the Part# column.

Comment: Something is odd here.  I tested that `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` query to confirm it returns only the rows where my `ItemDesc` field contains a "-".  When I stored "Ergodyne_Test" in the field, that row was not included in the `SELECT` results.

Comment: The `UPDATE` should respect that `WHERE` clause just the same, and not store anything in the `[Part#]` field when `ItemDesc` does not include a "-".  If you're certain the `[Part#]` values which shouldn't be there are not hold-overs from a previous `UPDATE` attempt, all I can suggest is to upload a copy of your database to a file sharing site and give us a link.

Comment: You were right, they were hold-overs from the previous update. Thank you again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not explicitly clear what to do for the case where ItemDesc lacks the hyphen symbol as a delimiter, but here is my suggestion. Use the substring function to grab everything to the right of the hyphen, where everything to the right is bound by the index of the hyphen character plus one, and the length of the string:

```
update user.table
set Part# = substring(ItemDesc, (CHARINDEX('-', ItemDesc)+1), LEN(ItemDesc) )
```

Taking your statement from the comments:

```
UPDATE tblIOT1 
SET Part#= Trim(Mid(ItemDesc, InStr(ItemDesc, '-') +1)) 
where ItemDesc like "*-*"
```

Note that I am using the star character and the other respondent uses the percent character, either appear to be valid to MS Access as specified [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx%20here)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I keep getting an error from the "From" statement. I'm really new to Access...can I be writing it wrong?

Comment: I think that was a sloppy edit and you don't need a from clause. My mistake.

Comment: Hmmmm still isn't working.... I tried this statement: UPDATE tblIOT1 SET Part#= Trim(Mid(ItemDesc, InStr(ItemDesc, '-') +1)) Is seems to be working but like I said some of them don't have a "-" so I want those to be blank. Right now it's copying the whold field over. Have any ideas?

Comment: Add a where clause testing the existence of a hyphen in ItemDesc, so only ItemDesc fields with hyphens will have everything right of the hyphen copied over. I edited my answer above with your statement plus a where clause so the code could be formatted for readability.